# How can I read this grib1 file in R?

Tags: r, binaryfiles, grib

I have forecasting data from the Korean Weather Service.

The file types are Grib1 or Grib3.

Here is an example of the Grib1 file type: [precipitation of probability data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9hk899rCeVnVEs1aDB4QUFMYkk&authuser=0).

I would like to read this file using R and convert it to a csv file with a dataframe-like form.

Comment: There is a `ReadGrib` function in the `rNomads` package for reading "grib1" and "grib2" filetypes.

Comment: ReadGrib have to fill in level and variable element. there is no default.
And I don't know what is level and variable in my data

Comment: I'm faced with the same problem. I'm trying to use GribInfo to get levels and variables but I still can't understand the result.

Comment: Hey, I'm faceing the same trouble. Could anyone post a valuable howto for reading Grib1 files with R? My `rnomads::readgrib` command always comes out empty.

Answer (score 0):

The fields of wgrib output are colon (:) separated. The fourth column is the variable and the 12th column is the level

ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib/readme

Comment: I am currently having problems opening a Grib1 FWIW